# ¿Cómo devolver un PDF?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Me estoy conectando a un servicio externo que me devuelve un bytearray con un archivo PDF en bytes. La versión del PDF es 1.7.

Mi problema es que esta respuesta tengo que empaquetarla de alguna manera y devolverla al usuario con `HTTPResponse`.

El código que tengo ahora mismo es este:

```
with open("etiqueta-envio.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(datos_pdf)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="etiqueta-envio.pdf"'
response.write(f)
return response
```

Esto me devuelve un archivo y adobe dice que está corrupto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No lo vuelques a un archivo intermedio. Simplemente retorna los bytes que tienes en `datos_pdf`, con el `content_type` apropiado:

```py
return HttpResponse(datos_pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

**Actualización**. Esta respuesta presupone que `datos_pdf` es un string de bytes. Si lo que te llega del servidor externo lo recibes como un `bytearray()`, debes convertirlo a string de bytes así:

```py
return HttpResponse(bytes(datos_pdf), content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: mimetype está en desuso, ahora se usa content_type, pero aún así no funciona, sigue dandome el mismo error

Comment: Gracias por el aviso sobre `mimetype`. Respecto a que no funcione ¿será que ya está corrupto el contenido de la respuesta? ¿Has verificado que cuando la escribes a disco el pdf resultante es correcto?

Comment: Si guardo el fichero si puedo leerlo como un pdf y no tiene errores pero al usar `HttpResponse` lo devuelve corrupto.

Comment: El código que utilizo ahora mismo es este `response = HttpResponse(datos_pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    return response`

Comment: Pues para descartar otras cosas, puedes probar a enviar un pdf mínimo copiando el código de [este pastebin](https://pastebin.com/M3S9jiuJ). La cadena de bytes que he puesto en `datos_pdf` en ese ejemplo debería ser un pdf válido.

Comment: he encontrado el error, he imprimido por pantalla el valor para compararlo con el que me has pasado, el problema es que me devuelve esto `bytearray(b'%PDF-1.7 \n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3 \n1 0 obj  ... ` empieza por bytearray, dato que reconoce python como caracteres, solo tengo que modificarlo para eliminar esto y ya está, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @FDelgado Ah, entiendo. La función que usas para recoger la respuesta del servidor externo te lo devuelve en forma de `bytearray()`, y la llamada a `f.write()` lo serializaba a bytes, lo que explica que el archivo te saliera bien, pero aparentemente django no hace eso sino que lo convierte a su forma representable que es `"bytearray(b'...')"`. He actualizado la respuesta para convertir el bytearray a secuencia de bytes antes de retornarlo.

Comment: Gracias por la actualización, exactamente eso es lo que he hecho para transformarlo y poder devolverlo de forma correcta